# Установка Visual C++

Tags: ide, visual-studio

Подскажите, если у меня есть пакет vs2010ultimate, можно ли его превратить в express (мне нужен vc++), чтобы не скачивать отдельно express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, превратить один пакет в другой ни с технической, ни с лицензионной точки зрения вы не сможете: это разные продукты. Нужно скачивать и устанавливать Express отдельно. Хотя некоторые части установки, возможно, закачивать и не придется.

Comment: Плохо хотя логично было убрать все ненужные компоненты и оставить только те которые входия в  express, как с установкой версии W7 и выбора нужную версию.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то при установке VS 2010 Ultimate можно выбрать устанавливаемые компоненты, и поставить VS соответственно только с поддержкой VC++ проектов:

[image: Установка VS2010]

В случае отсутствия лицензии на VS 2010 Ultimate есть два бесплатных варианта:

1. Поставить Express версию - в большинстве случаев ее вполне достаточно
2. Зарегистрироваться по программе [WebsiteSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark) (В отличии от DreamSpark не нужно быть студентом) и получить абсолютно бесплатно лицензии на VS 2010 Professional, MS Expression, SQL Server, и Windows Server. Сам воспользовался этим вариантом.

Comment: Хочется чтобы это было легально, если нет лицензии на ultimate

Comment: Бесплатно можно поставить только Express или, если есть ISIC карточка - получить по программе Dreamspark, или , если ВУЗ участвует в программе MSDN AA, получить там. У самого стоит студия по MSDN AA. Минус - невозможность коммерческой разработки.

Comment: Только для себя, комерческого замысла нет.

Comment: Я обновил ответ с учетом Ваших комментариев, посмотрите